# post-liminal/GCR algebras

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

from Theorem 5.6.2 [Murphy-C* algebras and operator theory]:

let *(H , φ)* be an non zero irreducible representation of C* algebra *A*, and
let *I* be a closed ideal for *A*. 
Denote *(H',φ')* the **restriction** of *(H , φ)* to I.
Given *A/I* and *I* are postliminal algebras, and *I* is **not** contained in *Ker(φ)*:

there are two things i find confusing:

1) Why *(H',φ')* is a non zero representation?

2) When *b∊ I*, why is *φ(b)* compact iff  *φ'(b)* is compact?

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell,

1. If $(H,\varphi')$ is zero, then $\varphi'(b)=0$ for all $b\in I$, so $I\subset\ker\varphi$.
2. the compactness of an operator does not depend on its "complement". And you have $\varphi(b)=\varphi'(b)\oplus 0$ (from $H=H'\oplus(H')^\perp$).

Comment: Thank you Martin. But i still dont understand something, *φ′(b)* is defined as the restriction of *φ(b)* to [*φ(I)H*]. So why should it provide *φ(b)((H′)⊥) = {0}* ?    thx

Comment: Take any $x\in (H')^\perp$, and $y\in H$. Then $$\langle \varphi(b)x,y\rangle=\langle x,\varphi(b^*)y\rangle=0.$$ As this works for all $y\in H$, $\varphi(b)x=0$.